# Java's String's length function showting incorrect value

Tags: java, string, string-length

In the below code not sure why, but when we copy and paste the variable "data" then the even with the blank String it is showing length as 6. To test is please copy the same code snippet, it is working fine even if we create a new variable with same name(which is commented in below code). to test is please copy and paste code as is, as it is giving trouble only if we copy and paste it.

```
String data="﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿"; // Copy this string variable, when we print this it gives output as 6
//String data=""; //This show's correct value as 0
System.out.println(data.length());
```

Comment: Print the chars that the String holds, the byte numbers of each char.

Comment: and cast the individual string chars to int first, (int) data.charAt(i). then u can look in an ascii table what characters they are. i guess its non-printable ones ...

Answer (score 8):

The first `data` is holding 6 times `&#65279` (inspect it yourself in the browser) which is a Unicode Character for a zero width no-breaking-space. The next is an actual empty `String`. Everything is working just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have copied your code and paste it in online compier and looks like you get trespasser in your string, look how your code looks in compiler,

[image]

So, because of those six dots, it's printing string length as 6 and print it.

Answer (score 0):

Put the lenght in an integer first.

```
String data="";
int i = data.length();
System.out.println(i);
```

Edit: as told in an earlier comment:
data holds an unicode for an empty string if you want to print it like that. And the unicode is 6 characters long. Thats why you get 6 as an result.